# detect www. using sed

Tags: amazon-web-services, sed, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to sed and almost confused.
Here is what I have in the nginx folder of my project:

```
files:
 "/tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh":
owner: root
group: root
mode: "000644"
content: |
  #! /bin/bash

  CONFIGURED=`grep -c "return 301 https" /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`

  if [ $CONFIGURED = 0 ]
    then
      sed -i '/listen 8080;/a \    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }\n' /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules added"
      exit 0
    else
      logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules already set"
      exit 0
  fi
```

The above code works like a charm and basically redirects all the request to https if they are http request.
However I need to add a piece to check if the url has www and redirect to non www.
so for example www.test.com will be redirected to test.com.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: is this you are looking for `echo 'www.test.com' |sed 's/www\.//g'` ?

Comment: @ps  Thanks for the answer. so I think here is: sed -i '/listen 8080;/a \    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http")  where I get the current url and now I need to somehow fit what you suggest and I am struggling with it

Comment: Get rid of all the extraneous code from your question and add the sample input and expected output for just the sed command you're left with, i.e. create a [mcve] about the specific problem that you're asking for help with.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS recommended solution was to completely rewrite  "/etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf"

You can do this by adding this file in .ebextensions: https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/docker-sc/https-redirect-docker-sc.config

I made one extra tweak for www redirect:

```
           location / {
               set $redirect 0;
               if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
                 set $redirect 1;
               }
               if ($host ~ ^www\.(?<domain>.+)$) {
                 set $redirect 1;
               }
               if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
                 set $redirect 0;
               }
               if ($redirect = 1) {
                 return 301 https://ADDYOURDOMAINREDIRECTHERE$request_uri;
               }
```

*One more note, your ec2 instance may already have a bunch of config files that you tried while finding a solution. I suggest deploying your app with NO config in .ebextensions, and then Rebuild Environment from the ELB console.  This should give you a blank slate. Then simply add the file above to .ebextensions and redeploy.

*another note, you can ssh into your ec2 instance and verify that the file looks correct